# c++: Is the behavior of string::find for empty input string well defined

Tags: c++, string, language-lawyer

The following code snippet returns always true on my compiler(visual studio). But is this behavior well defined and portable?

```
bool return_always_true(std::string const& str)
{
    return str.find("") != std::string::npos;
}

int main(){
     cout << boolapha << return_always_true("") << endl
          << return_always_true("oxylottl") << endl
          << return_always_true("lorem ipsum") << endl;
 //true true true
}
```

Comment: You might want to [read a reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Comment: Yes, the empty string is a substring of every string.

Comment: from the cpprefence: `an empty substring is found at pos if and only if pos <= size()`

Comment: ok find for empty substring returns true if and only if position is zero. Wright?

Comment: yeah when you put pos=1 it should be return `npos` according to the definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I find [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) easier to read than the standard.  Quoting them:

> Finds the first substring equal to `str` ...
>
> Formally, a substring `str` is said to be found at position `xpos` if all of the following is true:
>
> 1. `xpos >= pos`
> 2. `xpos + str.size() <= size()`
> 3. for all positions `n` in `str`, `Traits::eq(at(xpos+n), str.at(n))`

An empty string will always match at the start of the target string because

1. 0 >= 0
2. 0+0 <= size()
3. There are no position is `str` so the match condition is vacuously true.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is: "an empty substring is found at pos if and only if pos <= size()"

Answer (score 3):

According to [Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find):

> - an empty substring is found at pos if and only if pos <= size()

`str.find("")` uses the third overload for `std::basic_string::find` which has a signature of :

```
size_type find( const CharT* s, size_type pos = 0 ) const;
```

Which means that `pos` starts at `0` so `pos <= size()` is *always* true.

Yes, the behaviour is well defined and portable.